# 2.9.1 no Rock or Modular Tree Generator / Installed but no menu pick

Tags: add-on

In 2.9.1.0 I've installed the Rock Generator and the Modular Tree add-ons but there are no menu picks for them under Add.  The do warn that I need to 'upgrade' to 2.8 to use them.  Does anyone have them working in 2.9.1 and/or know of a good free solution for 2.9.1 for generating rocks and trees?

Comment: Modular tree addon works from a node editor, not from adding mesh. Ive never used rock generator though, so i dont know about it

Comment: Rock generator is under add Mesh > extra objects iirc

Comment: Forgive my noobishness - WRT Modular Tree - I cannot find the 'Node Editor'.  The doc for Modular Tree says "View3D > Tools > Tree > Make Tree".  I've looked for a 'Node Editor' but 'Editor Types" do not have a "Node Editor".  I've looked 3DViewport in both Object and Edit mode and at the (T)ools and (N) menus but I just can't find it.  It's definitely showing as installed.  thx in advance!